# React: Facing an issue to get the selected table row ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone please guide me, how can I write a code that will dynamically give me the selected row index number so that I can use that index to edit/delete this row?

Code I used:

```
handleRowSelect (index) {
    debugger;
    console.log(index);
    var myData = this.state.thisData;
    console.log(myData);
    var OK = _.indexOf(myData, myData[1]);
    var test = this.state.thisData[1];
    console.log(test);
};
```

Specifying the index on my state thisData[1] gives me a result as I was expecting but can't make it dynamic, as am learning React at the moment.
Any Guidance would be very helpful.

Thanking in Advance

### UPDATE

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      thisData: []
    };
    let app = fire.database().ref('timelogdata');
    app.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.getData(snapshot.val());
    });
    this.taskOnSubmit = this.taskOnSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRowSelect = this.handleRowSelect.bind(this);
   }

   getData(values){
    let messagesVal = values;
    let messages = _(messagesVal)
                      .keys()
                      .map(messageKey => {
                          let cloned = _.clone(messagesVal[messageKey]);
                          cloned.key = messageKey;
                          return cloned;
                      })
                      .value();
      this.setState({
        thisData: messages
      });
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
    };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
    };

  handleRowSelect (index) {
    debugger;
    console.log(index);
    // console.log(key);
    var myData = this.state.thisData;
    console.log(myData);
    var OK = _.indexOf(myData, myData[1]);
    var test = this.state.thisData[1];
    // var test = this.state.thisData[{i}];
    console.log(test);
    console.log(OK);
  };

  componentWillMount () {
    // let testData = [];
    // for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //   testData.push({ code: `code${i}`, name: `name${i}`, group: `group${i % 2}` });
    // }
    this.setState({
      open: false
      // "thisData": testData
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }
  taskOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    let newData = {"code": "code10", "name": "name10", "group": "group10"};
    // let dbCon = fire.database().ref('timelogdata');
    fire.database().ref('timelogdata').push(newData);
    var thisArray = this.state.thisData;
    let newRow = thisArray.push(newData);
    this.setState({
      thisData: thisArray
    });
  };

render() {
  const data = this.state.thisData.slice();
  const actions = [
    <FlatButton
      label="Cancel"
      primary={true}
      onClick={this.handleClose}
    />,
    <FlatButton
      label="Submit"
      primary={true}
      keyboardFocused={true}
      onClick={this.taskOnSubmit}
    />,
  ];
return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div style={{ height: 1000}}>
          <SussolReactTable
            columns={columns}
            tableData={data}
            cellDataKey="code"
            onSelection={this.handleRowSelect}
          />
          <RaisedButton 
            label="Dialog" 
            onClick={this.handleOpen} 
            backgroundColor="rgb(242, 101, 50)"
            />
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Actions"
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}>
          <TextField
            hintText="Username"
            floatingLabelText="Enter username"
            ref="loginUserName"
          /><br/>
          <TextField
            hintText="Username"
            floatingLabelText="Enter something"
            ref="loginSomething"
          />
        </Dialog>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `handleRowSelect()` please

Comment: Hi Sme, `<div style={{ height: 1000}}>
          <SussolReactTable
            columns={columns}
            tableData={data}
            cellDataKey="code"
            onSelection={this.handleRowSelect}
          />`

Comment: Could you add the full code for more context?

Comment: @JohnKennedy: Added the full code.

Comment: I assume `<SussolReactTable />` isn't a component you created. But I can see that it gives you the `index` from the `onSelected` function. I also see you pass an array `data` into the `SussolReactTable`. Have you tried `var test = this.state.thisData[index];` ?

Comment: Yeah, you should try what @sme said. If that doesn't work, you might want to use codesanbox.io for replicating your project. Do not expose your secret keys while doing so.

Comment: Yes, i didn't.
It's a table component created by someone I used it same as other table components for instance Material UI.
Yes, I tried, doesn't give me the value as expected. 
although: Giving specific index to that line of code does give the result.

So i don't know, how can i make it dynamic.

Comment: Ok, well I see that you pass in `cellDataKey='code'`, and `code` is a property of the elements in the array. Assuming that in the array, the value of `code` is unique to each element, try this: `let test; for (let i = 0; i < this.state.thisData.length; i++) { if (this.state.thisData[i].code === index) { test = this.state.thisData[i]; break; } }`. Gotta use a loop because I assume you aren't using a library such as lodash.

Comment: Or if you are using lodash, `let test = _.find(this.state.thisData, (x) => x.code === index);`

Comment: I will give it a try.
Well, I did used a library lodash: If you see this function handleRowSelect, i used the lodash library syntax:
var OK = _.indexOf(myData, myData[1]);

Comment: when you console log index, does the correct index get printed? Because maybe the handler is passing more parameters than you're reading.

Comment: @sme: 
used the way you mentioned inside, handleRowSelect, the values returned said: Undefined, using Lodash and without.
Though, I tried this code:
`var test = _.findIndex(myData, {'name': 'test', 'code':'7','group':'group'});`
Index returned on console is accurate.

Inside same method code: `console.log(index);`  returned :

`[{…}]0: rows: (2) [4, 4]0: 41: 4length: 2__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)`

the [4,4], the index seems to be taken, don't know how can i get that index from that

Comment: Component <SussolReactTable /> is made using BluePrint table.